# Compare two text-strings and merge them if start and end are identical

Tags: php, regex

**Edited**

How can I compare two text-strings in a way to check if the end of string1 is the same as the beginning of string2. The string-length and the matching part are variable. As a result I want to merge both strings.

```
$string1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur';
$string2 = 'amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr 123';

$result = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr 123';
```

I don't know in which way I can handle that, so I don't know how to start.

Comment: Have you tried any thing ?

Comment: I really don't know how to start with that :-(

Comment: Do you need that only for this string or for this pattern? Also how do you define `start` and `end` the first/last 2 words or 3???

Comment: @Rizier123 Think of it like a panorama for text.

Comment: start and end is variable in length - which is the problem for me...

Comment: I am sorry to ask but the string1 and string2 do not qualify to be merged here! Am i understanding it correct?

Comment: @MixedVeg: The end of string1 is identical to the beginning of string2. So I want to merge both strings to get es complete sentence.

Comment: k i've put enough into my answer.  just to attempt it first before asking questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function create_text_panorama(array $strings)
{
    $joined = array();
    $strings_length = count($strings);

    if ($strings_length <= 1) {
        return $strings;
    }

    $joined[] = $strings[0];

    for ($i = 1; $i < $strings_length; $i++) {
        $current  = $strings[$i];

        $prev     = $strings[$i-1];
        $prev_len = strlen($prev);

        $p = 0;

        for ($j = 0; $j < $prev_len; $j++) {
            if (!isset($current[$p]) || $prev[$j] !== $current[$p]) {
                $p = 0;
            } else {
                $p++;
            }
        }

        if ($p > 0) {
            $joined[count($joined) - 1] .= substr($current, $p + 1);
        } else {
            $joined[] = $current;
        }
    }

    return $joined;
}

echo '<pre>';

$strings = array('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur', 'amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr 123');
print_r(create_text_panorama($strings));
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr 123
)
```

Easy really.

Comment: There is a missing space in the result `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetursadipscing elitr 123`

Comment: I made some changes to it, might have fixed it.

Comment: You can initialise `$j` to `$prev_len - strlen($current)` instead of zero, shaving off a few comparisons.

Comment: Ehh, and make sure it doesn't become negative of course :D

Comment: @Ja͢ck Edit the answer, im not sure how you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to find the longest prefix of B that matches the suffix of A.

```
function merge($a, $b)
{
    $suffix_len = strlen($b); // assume $b matches the suffix of $a

    // compare suffix of $a with prefix of $b
    while ($suffix_len && substr_compare($a, $b, -$suffix_len, $suffix_len) != 0) {
        --$suffix_len; // remove one character off the end
    }
    // test whether we have a match
    return $suffix_len ? $a . substr($b, $suffix_len) : $a;
}

echo merge('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur', 'amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr 123');
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an approach:

```
<?php
$content = array('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur',
'amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr 123');
for ($i=0; $i <count($content)-1 ; $i++) { 
    $pos=0;
    $counter=0;
    while ($counter<strlen($content[$i+1])) {
        $end=substr($content[$i],strlen($content[$i])-$counter++);
        $start=$content[$i+1];
        if (strpos($start,$end)===0) {
            $pos=$counter-1;
        }
    }
    $content[$i]=$content[$i].substr($content[$i+1], $pos-1);
}
echo $content[0];
```